# How to show $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}) \cup (\frac{3\pi}{4}, 2\pi)$ is sequentially separated?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, connectedness, separation-axioms

Definition of separated:

> $E$ is separated if $A, B \neq \varnothing$, $A \cup B = E$, and there are not convergent sequences in $A$ that have limit points in $B$, and vice versa.

Definition of convergent sequence:

> $x_n \to x$ if $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists N$ such that $\forall n \geq N$, $d(x_n, x) < \epsilon$.

It's pretty intuitive that the intervals $[0, \frac{\pi}{2})$ and $(\frac{3\pi}{4}, 2\pi)$ are separated, but it's not intuitive to me that there aren't any sequences in one interval that can't converge to a limit point in the other interval. But when I think about convergent sequence geometrically, it means that if I have some small neighborhood about the limit point, it contains terms in the sequence, or something like that. However I don't know how to rigorize this notion in terms of an official proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume by contradiction there is a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $A=[0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ converging to a limit $a\in B=(\frac{3\pi}{4},2\pi)$. In particular, for $$\varepsilon\stackrel{\rm def}{=} \frac{\frac{3\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi}{2}}{4}$$
there exists $N_\varepsilon$ such that for any $n\geq N_\varepsilon$, $\lvert a_n - a\rvert \leq \varepsilon$. But as $a\in B$ and $a_n \in A$, we have for all $n\geq 0$
$$
\lvert a_n - a\rvert \geq \inf_{x\in A, y\in B} \lvert x-y \rvert = \frac{3\pi}{4} - \frac{\pi}{2}  > \varepsilon
$$
leading to a contradiction. (The other direction -- limits in $A$ of sequences in $B$ -- is similar)

Comment: What does the notation $\inf_{x\in A, y\in B}$ mean?

Comment: [It's similar to the $\min$, except that it may not be actually realized.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum) I.e., it is the infimum (roughly the same as minimum) over all $x\in A$ and $y\in B$.

Comment: The quantity to minimize is the difference $\lvert x-y\rvert$, not the values of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized my error after I made my comment and deleted it before you replied